# pair's occurrences in a list

Tags: python, python-itertools

I have a dictionary with some specific query per session. The key-values are ID numbers of a specific session, and the item-values are the queries searched, like this:

```
1000 , [ Malaria, Cholera ]
1001 , [ Disease, Malaria, Fever]
1002 , [ Fever, Cholera, AIDS, Cancer, Sickness]
1003 , [ Sickness, Disease, Fever, Constipation]
```

I would like to found the cooccurrences of a specific query for all the sessions( example: Disease, 2occurrences: [(Fever, 2times),(Malaria, 1time),(Sickness, 1 times),(Constipation, 1time)]. I have tried with that code, trying with a library that I have read can help me, itertool:

```
for x in occurrences.values():
    if len(x) > 2:
        for y in x:
            for pair in itertools.combinations(y, 2):
                coccurr[pair]+=1


for k in cooccurr.keys():
    print k, len(cooccurr[k])
```

the script runs without errors, but it doesn't print anything, neither an empty list. Which is my error? I use itertools correctly?

Comment: so you basically want the count of each word

Comment: coccurr and cooccurr are not the same.

Comment: Not only, for every word to count its numbers, and to enumerate the words that appear together with that word

Comment: @Lupanoide can you be more clear provide sample input and output a little more clear

Comment: @poke I don't want that, Perhaps I have written not well my post, but I would like to count the numbers of queries that appear together with a specific query. example: Disease, 2occurrences: [(Fever, 2times),(Malaria, 1time),(Sickness, 1 times),(Constipation, 1time)]

Comment: @Lupanoide so you would be giving a input and output should be all the words and count for the related input

Comment: @Vignesh Kalai, Ok, many persons has misunderstood my question, so I try to be more clear. Given the dictionary of query per session, I would like to create another dictionary that show all the queries submitted together with a specific query. So to my example if I would like to search Sickness, for example, my output should be:                                                                           Sickness: [(Fever,2),(Cholera,1),(AIDS,1),(Cancer,1)(Disease,1)(Constipation,1)]

Comment: @Lupanoide I’ve updated my answer; please comment on my answer the next time you want to address it. Otherwise I won’t be notified.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
from collections import Counter
def findForQuery (queries, value):
    related = Counter()
    count = 0
    for query in queries.values():
        if value in query:
            count += 1
            related.update({item: 1 for item in query if item != value})
    return count, related

queries = {
    1000: [ 'Malaria', 'Cholera' ],
    1001: [ 'Disease', 'Malaria', 'Fever'],
    1002: [ 'Fever', 'Cholera', 'AIDS', 'Cancer', 'Sickness'],
    1003: [ 'Sickness', 'Disease', 'Fever', 'Constipation']
}
```

Used like this:

```
>>> findForQuery(queries, 'Disease')
(2, Counter({'Fever': 2, 'Malaria': 1, 'Constipation': 1, 'Sickness': 1}))
>>> findForQuery(queries, 'Sickness')
(2, Counter({'Fever': 2, 'AIDS': 1, 'Constipation': 1, 'Cancer': 1, 'Disease': 1, 'Cholera': 1}))
```

Comment: so update here adds the value does not replaces the old value nice :)

Comment: It’s the fancy way of doing `for item in items: c[item] += 1` ;D

Comment: I'd probably opt for the 2-line `c[item] += 1` version in practice. The update/dict comprehension is clever, but it's not immediately apparent what it's doing until you think about it, whereas you know right away what the other does.

Comment: Ok, perfect, that one runs. Thanks a lot, Poke